# Different result for String and Integers using JSON in python

Tags: python, json, tree

**EDIT:**
As @Alfe suggested in the comments, the exact problem in this case is that the following code is unable to handle nodes with same values. So, How do I get the expected output, without changing the value of the nodes?

I'm executing following code to make a tree from JSON data:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import sys

# Tree in JSON format
s = '{"Harry": {"children": ["Bill", {"Jane": {"children": [{"Diane": {"children": ["Mary"]}}, "Mark"]}}]}}'

# Convert JSON tree to a Python dict
data = json.loads(s)

# Extract tree edges from the dict
edges = []

def get_edges(treedict, parent=None):
    name = next(iter(treedict.keys()))
    if parent is not None:
        edges.append((parent, name))
    for item in treedict[name]["children"]:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            get_edges(item, parent=name)
        else:
            edges.append((name, item))

get_edges(data)

# Dump edge list in Graphviz DOT format
print('strict digraph tree {')
for row in edges:
    print('    {0} -> {1};'.format(*row))
print('}')
```

Command used at terminal: `python filename.py | dot -Tpng -otree.png`

With String input, as shown in the code above, the output is:
[image]

But if I enter JSON data with integers:

`s = '{"92": {"children": [{"87": {"children": [87, 96]}}, {"96": {"children": [90, 105]}}]}}'`

I get following output: (which is wrong!)

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How to solve this issue?

Comment: From the input JSON that looks like the right output: Can you show another example and give what you expect as output?

Comment: Must haves of all bug reports: ① situation & input, ② observed behavior, ③ expected behavior.  You provided some information which is very valuable, namely ① what you did, ② what you received and additionally that you find it wrong.  You now need to provide us the ③: what you expected instead.

Comment: Added expected output. @TemporalWolf

Comment: @Alfe, added expected output in the question.

Comment: I think you have a different idea what the names of the nodes mean than the library you are using.  For the library the names are IDs which means there can be only one node with any given ID, while you consider them only names which means there can be more than one node with the same name.  My proposal would be to differentiate the names (the two 96s and the two 87s) by adding suffixes ("96a" and "96b" or similar).

Comment: @Alfe, I recon that's exactly the problem. Your suggestion is indeed a way to solve this problem.  But I'm not sure how am I supposed to deal with suffixes and not change the actual value of node, How do I code it?

Comment: I tried this: `dot -Tpng -otree.png <<<"strict digraph tree { 92 -> 87 -> \"87a\"; 87 -> \"96a\"; 92 -> 96 -> 90; 96 -> 105 }"` and it worked out of the box, so if you have different IDs, this solves the problem.  In your code you just have to use different IDs as well, e.g. like this: `s = '{"92": {"children": [{"87": {"children": ["87a", "96a"]}}, {"96": {"children": [90, 105]}}]}}'`.

Comment: Yes, that works, I have tried a lot of different inputs. Whenever all of them are different, the tree is generated perfectly. The problem is when the nodes have similar values. What you are suggesting here, is to change the value of node, which changes the purpose of my program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126212/discussion-between-grimlock-and-alfe).

Comment: I added a proper answer below (it was time for this).

Answer (score 2):

Editting based on the *edit* in the question:

As far as your output is considered, it is giving me:

```
92 -> 87;
87 -> 87;
87 -> 96;
92 -> 96;
96 -> 90;
96 -> 105;
```

It is showing `"87"` and `87` as same because you are using `.format()` with `print` which inserts the value in string independent of maintaing the quotes `"`. For example:

```
>>> '{}'.format(1)
'1'
>>> '{}'.format('1')
'1'
```

In order to fix this, you may do:

```
for parent, child in edges:
    parent = '"{}"'.format(parent)  if isinstance(parent, str) else parent
    child = '"{}"'.format(child)  if isinstance(child, str) else child
    print('    {0} -> {1};'.format(parent, child))
```

which prints:

```
"92" -> "87";
"87" -> 87;
"87" -> 96;
"92" -> "96";
"96" -> 90;
"96" -> 105;
```

Comment: Yes, leaf nodes stay without quotes! Anyway to get the expected output? I have added expected output.

Comment: @Grimlock: Check my edited answer. Added your doubt at the last

Comment: Still getting the same image output with this result!

Comment: My output mentioned at the last is based on your code, with the changes I made in `for` loop. I believe this is what you desire. If still you are getting previous output, you must not updated the code.

Comment: No, I already tried it, it doesn't work. You can try yourself if you have graphviz installed. I've added the console command to the question.

Comment: I do not have that setup in my machine, I do not even know what it does. But definitely it is not the issue with your code in that case as it is working on *Python's shell*. Probably it is the issue with *Graphviz* as in your first graph, it is showing the `name` without `"`. Maybe internally it converts all the value to string which it later uses for the display purpose

Comment: It does exactly this.  Quotes are stripped.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is rather one with using the tool `dot` which unifies strings and numbers, hence it regards the nodes with equal names as identical (meaning: being just one).  You need to have unique IDs for each node.  The graphical output then can be tweaked to reflect the equal names in different nodes.

Example:

```
echo '
strict digraph tree {
  92 -> 87 -> "87a";
  "87a" [label="87"];
  87 -> "96a";
  "96a" [label="96"];
  92 -> 96 -> 90;
  96 -> 105 }
' | dot -Tpng -otree.png
```

This will produce exactly the output you wanted (with directed edges).

I changed your code accordingly to implement this tweak:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import print_function
import json
import sys

# Tree in JSON format
s = '{"92": {"children": [{"87": {"children": [87, 96]}}, {"96": {"children": [90, 105]}}]}}'

# Convert JSON tree to a Python dict
data = json.loads(s)

# Extract tree edges from the dict
edges = []

def x(node):
    return '%s%s' % (node, type(node))

def get_edges(treedict, parent=None):
    name = next(iter(treedict.keys()))
    if parent is not None:
        edges.append((x(parent), x(name), parent, name))
    for item in treedict[name]["children"]:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            get_edges(item, parent=name)
        else:
            edges.append((x(name), x(item), name, item))

get_edges(data)

# Dump edge list in Graphviz DOT format
print('strict digraph tree {')
for row in edges:
    print('    "{0}" -> "{1}"; "{0}" [label="{2}"]; "{1}" [label="{3}"];'.format(*row))
print('}')
```

This uses special internal node IDs which combine the node names and their type (str/unicode or int), and sets a label for each node hiding this internal ID again.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm trying to achieve, but it works only for given example. For example: If I try to put this: `s = '{"82": {"children": [{"80": {"children": [{"74": {"children": [79, 79, 82]}}, {"78": {"children": [70, 71, 87]}}, {"84": {"children": [76, 80, 91]}}]}}, {"80": {"children": [{"81": {"children": [85, 86, 88]}}, {"81": {"children": [77, 81, 83]}}, {"85": {"children": [77, 83, 91]}}]}}, {"89": {"children": [{"85": {"children": [80, 81, 83]}}, {"95": {"children": [87, 102, 103]}}, {"95": {"children": [87, 92, 96]}}]}}]}}'` then it won't generate result as required.

Comment: I really should look up for some other library to convert this JSON data into a tree, any suggestions?

Comment: Again:  what result would you like to have in this new example?

Comment: It's not complete, but I believe it's understandable. http://i.imgur.com/XU2MGcB.jpg